# How to query 2 tables to create a mapping of one foreign key to the name value of the other

Tags: sql

Say i have two tables. The first lets' called `info_join_table` one looks like:

```
+-------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| prospect_id | some_unrelated_column | degree_offering_id |
+-------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|           1 | pork                  |               1000 |
|           2 | beef                  |               1001 |
|           3 | mutton                |               1002 |
+-------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

and the other degree_offering table

```
+------+---------+
|  id  |  name   |
+------+---------+
| ...  |         |
| 1000 | chem    |
| 1001 | math    |
| 1002 | english |
+------+---------+
```

I want output that looks like:

```
[[1, chem], [2, math], [3, english]]
```

How do I do this? Basically, I want to query the `info_join_table` without the unrelated column but with the `degree_offering_id` replaced by its corresponding `name` in the `degree_offering` table. How do I do this?

Comment: I think you are describing a `JOIN`.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You join the tables on their shared id and only select those two fields in the output.

select info_join_table.prospect_id, degree_offering.name
from table1 join table2  on info_join_table.degree_offering_id = degree_offering.id